# shutil.move() not working after reading object with pywin32

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, shutil

I've got a script that is intended to sort my photo/video collection (Windows).  The photos work fine as they are sortable by EXIF which is easily accessed.

Videos are harder because I have to get the file's "Media Creation Date" which is readable by only pywin32, to my understanding.  However, once I've accessed the media creation date, `shutil.move()` does not work.  It throws no error, it just runs indefinitely without progress until I manually kill the script:

Here's the snippet in question:

```
from datetime import datetime
import exifread
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
from win32com.propsys import propsys, pscon

# get the file list, do stuff with photos, etc
# f is the file
# cr is the path root to which it will be moved

    elif str(f).lower().endswith(("mp4", "mov")):
        props = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(f)
        dt = props.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Media_DateEncoded).GetValue()
        year, month = str(dt.year), str(dt.month).zfill(2)
        new_fn = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")
        new_fn = f"{new_fn}{os.path.splitext(f)[1]}"
        move_path = os.path.join(cr, year, month, new_fn)
        print(f"SRC: {f}")
        print(f"DESTINATION: {move_path}")
        print("----------------------------------")
        shutil.move(f, move_path)
```

It prints the source correctly, and the destination correctly, but does not move the file.  I have also tried `os.rename()` and `os.replace()` with the same result, which suggests that perhaps the `propsys` method still has a lock on the file?  How do I free up this file for moving?

Comment: Are the paths absolute? If not, you might want to check the actual working directory.

Comment: Hi @Timus yes, the paths are absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `propsys` is blocking the file (you can check in Process Explorer), try just deleting it:

```py
fpath = r'c:\temp\user\t\test.mp4'
move_path = r'c:\temp\user\t\test moved.mp4'
props = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(fpath)
print( props.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Media_DateEncoded).GetValue() )
del props
shutil.move(fpath , move_path)
```